# Android : Database data validation through SQL or Java?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, validation

**TL; DR**

Are there any well-known patterns/strategies that can be used for data validation based on data in a database table in Android apps?

---

Consider an SQLite database table that has the following columns :

1. start_date
2. start_time
3. end_date
4. end_time

I need to ensure that a record cannot be inserted into the above table if the start_date, start_time or end_date, end_time of the record to be inserted falls in the range of an existing record.

**Example :**

Existing record

```
start_date    end_date   start_time    end_time

2019-02-11    2019-02-15    22:00       23:30
```

New record to be inserted

```
start_date    end_date   start_time    end_time

2019-02-12    2019-02-13    22:00       23:30
```

Since the above record falls between the date and time range of the existing record, the insert should not be allowed by the UI.

With the above example in mind, there are 2 ways in which I can perform this validation :

1. Formulate a self-sufficient SQL Query that will check if the date-time range of the new record to be inserted falls in the date-time range of an existing record. If such a record exists, don't allow the new record to be inserted **OR**
2. Query all the records from the table, iterate through them one by one in `Java` code (via a `Cursor`) and if any row falls in the date range, don't allow the insert.

Given the fact that the use-case for the app is such that the table in question will most probably not have more than 20-30 records, fetching all the rows and iterating through them using a `Cursor` in `Java` wouldn't really be that costly 
in comparison to running an SQL query. On the flip-side, a complex database query on 20-30 records may result in more I/O.

The above two approaches come to mind for validating data before it can be inserted into the database. I am assuming data validation from a database table is a common use-case in Android apps.

**Are there any well-known patterns/strategies that can be used for data validation based on data in a database table in Android apps?**

Comment: FYI, the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library offers the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) and [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) classes for this kind of work. They have methods such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, `contains`, `encloses`, `union`, etc. But I do not know if they work in Android or not.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque Forgive my ignorance but I believe what you are presenting are APIs for date-time comparison. What the OP wants to know is whether they should read all the rows from the table and check if the new row to be inserted falls between the date-time range of any of these rows OR whether they should just write an SQL query that will check if the new date falls between an existing row date-time. Hope it's clear now..

Comment: @CKing # 2 “Query all the records from the table, iterate through them one by one in Java code”… which should be done using the classes I pointed out. And for # 1, the way to specify the date and time parameters is through a prepared statement with placeholders where you pass the date-time classes I pointed out.

Comment: @BasilBourque The question is not about how to do it. The question is which one of the approaches is better? Validate data through SQL query that will cause I/O or validate data in memory in Java which will need all the rows to be loaded into the memory for that table. No where in my question have I asked what API should I use or how to write a query to compare dates. I am asking what approach to use and if there are any other approaches that can be considered.Hope this clarifies the question further?